# How do I revoke (grant drop on any table) from a user?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a user with privilege Drop on Any Table. I need to revoke that. They only should have drop privileges on their own tablespace.

My setup is three schemas, production, reporting and ETL transfers if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
REVOKE DROP ANY TABLE FROM X
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Oracle

Syntax:

Revoke DROP Any Table from

In SQL Server

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlsecurity/thread/c562ef25-3157-4068-8957-9095e31b1ffc/